# SQL Server 2008 - big increase in size of the table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

One year ago table contained 31 million rows, now contains 36 million rows,
a table size is increased from 9 GB to 45 GB. The table contains 40 columns of type varchar (30) and one varchar(255), the total size of about 1500 bytes. Recovery mode is simple, and the log is of normal size. A year ago the DB was moved to SQL Server 2005 from SQL Server 2008. What could have caused such a  big increase in table size?
Thank you

Comment: Here are some details: rows:36000000 reserved:47000000 KB data: 45000000 KB index_size:1800000 KB unused: 5000 KB

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're looking at size of the table in SSMS and it differentiates between data size (data stored in the table) and index size (data stored in non-clustered indexes).

- Longer strings in your `VARCHAR(N)` fields
- New columns
- New indexes
- Turned off compression

Comment: And data type changes / column additions, though the OP didn't state any schema changes.

Comment: +1 - the table could just be bigger ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Do have a clustered index?
- Index maintenance is running on new server?

Comment: Yes, there is a clustered index.
Here are some details:
rows:36000000  
reserved:47000000 KB  
data: 45000000 KB  
index_size:1800000 KB 
unused: 5000 KB